# Aloof proper usage

Tags: word-choice, grammar, word-usage

So is it a good use of the word aloof to say "She is not aloof to their harsh judgements"? The intent is to say that a person is aware of the perception others have of them. Thanks.

Comment: 'Aloof to' **is** certainly used, though I'd use 'aloof from' here.

Comment: @mplungjan,  “perceptive of” is more natural than “perceptive to”, which I would not expect to hear from an informed speaker.

Comment: I am not infallible - and it was early :(

Comment: "She [is aware of]/[knows about] their harsh judgements" would also work and be easier to read due to the absence of double negations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what the actual state of affairs is, you may use one of these.There are slight subtleties in the difference of meaning and usage.

**Unaware** which means *'**having no knowledge of a situation or fact**'.*

*She is not unaware of their harsh judgments.*

**Oblivious** which means, '***not aware of or concerned about what is happening around one***'.

*She is not oblivious to their harsh judgments.*

If you are saying that she is aware and affected by them, then you may use **impervious**.

***Impervious means'unable to be affected by'.***

*She is not impervious to their harsh judgments.*

I am using these words as you have paired them with 'no'.A positive sentence construction with their antonyms could work as well.

Comment: '. . .insensitive to . . .' works.